# How to get two dictionary values into a single string?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsmutabledictionary

I have JSON Response like

```
q13 =     {
    multiple = multiple;
    restrict = all;
    title1 = "Board Certification:";
    title2 = "Exp Date:";
    type = "double_text";
    value1 =         (
        "Test Certificate"
    );
    value2 =         (
        "12/14/27"
    );
};
```

Now in that JSON response I need only values of value1 and value2 and those two values must be stored in a single string separated by comma(,).

How can it be done?

Comment: both keys,  value1 and value2 contain list(array) as value. you need to extract the object from array first then append them with ",".

Comment: For suppose there are more than one index (let it be 4 index's) in each array(value1 & value2). Now i have to combine 1st index of value1 with 1st index of value2 and 2nd index of value1 with 2nd index of value2 and vice versa. how it can be done.

Comment: there are so many ways to solve it. here is one approach " make a dictionary with (value 1 array as keys) and (value 2 array as values) [init(objects:forKeys:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdictionary/1410010-init). after that loop through the dictionary keys and make a string with current key and value. end result  would be similar to this "Test Certificate, 12/14/27"

Comment: ThankYou @pawan it worked for me

Comment: Okay, but @parvendra-singh solution is more better. i just gave you another approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple do it like this.
If you have multiple values in your both array.

```
NSDictionary *dictionary =[your_Json_Object valueForKey:@"q13"];
NSArray *value1Array = [dictionary valueForKey:@"value1"];
NSArray *value2Array = [dictionary valueForKey:@"value2"];

NSMutableString *combinedString = [NSMutableString new];

[value1Array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *str1, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

    NSString * innerCombinedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  %@",str1,[value2Array objectAtIndex:idx]];
    [combinedString appendString:innerCombinedString];
    if (idx != value1Array.count) {
      [combinedString appendString:@","];
    }

}];
```

Comment: Your logic can't work if there are more that one object  in value1Array arrray.

Comment: Your edited ans is correct. You can check my answer. You will more idea without looping.

Comment: Bro your idea is also good and perfect but it returns like this :

Test Certificate  Test Certificate  Test Certificate  Test Certificate ,  12/14/27  12/14/27 12/14/27 12/14/27

And my idea will give like this :

Test Certificate 12/14/27, Test Certificate 12/14/27,  Test Certificate 12/14/27, Test Certificate 12/14/27  .....  So let him decide what he want ...  :)

Comment: He said that he need in one string, so did it ;)

Comment: i actually need Test certificate and 12/14/27 in one string. Thank you @nimalsinh.

Comment: if you like my answer then please tick it for upvote :) @saikiran

Answer (score 0):

Just i create two NSmutabledictionary and get in one string. U have any doubt let me know i explain.

```
 NSMutableDictionary *Dict_Value;
 NSMutableDictionary *Dict_Value1;

 Dict_Value = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[Dict_Value setObject:@"FirstDict" forKey:@"One"];
[Dict_Value setObject:@"FirstDict" forKey:@"Two"];
[Dict_Value setObject:@"FirstDict" forKey:@"Three"];
[Dict_Value setObject:@"FirstDict" forKey:@"Four"];

Dict_Value1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];


[Dict_Value1 setObject:@"2Multiple1" forKey:@"2One"];
[Dict_Value1 setObject:@"2Multiple2" forKey:@"2Two"];
[Dict_Value1 setObject:@"2Multiple3" forKey:@"2Three"];
[Dict_Value1 setObject:@"2Multiple4" forKey:@"2Four"];


NSString *string= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Dict1 %@, Dict2 %@",[Dict_Value valueForKey:@"Value1"],[Dict_Value1 valueForKey:@"Value2"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below is your dic which you will get in JSON:

```
 NSMutableDictionary *dicMain = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    dicMain[@"multiple"] = @"multiple";
    dicMain[@"restrict"] = @"all";
    dicMain[@"title1"] = @"Board Certification:";
    dicMain[@"title2"] = @"Exp Date:";
    dicMain[@"type"] = @"double_text";

    dicMain[@"value1"] = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Test Certificate"];
    dicMain[@"value2"] = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"12/14/27"];
```

Here is logic to get values into one string:

```
NSArray *aryValue1 = [dicMain valueForKey:@"value1"];
NSArray *aryValue2 = [dicMain valueForKey:@"value2"];
NSString *strFinalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[aryValue1 componentsJoinedByString:@" "],[aryValue2 componentsJoinedByString:@" "]];

NSLog(@"%@",strFinalString);
```